# How to convert Jquery $(document).scrollTop() code to React JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, event-handling

How to convert jQuery scroll code to ReactJS ?

```
if($(".app-wizard-header").length > 0) {            
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {                  
      this.setState({Headerbg:'app-wizard-header'})          
  } else {                 
      this.setState({Headerbg:'app-wizard-header no-bg'})          
  }
}
```

Comment: what do u mean by convert to ReactJs? You need to find when the respective code should execute and execute it at that time.

Comment: @Panther: Yes I just want to convert entire code in to ReactJs.

Comment: In vanilla JavaScript, you can create a div at the top with an id="top", and when a user performs an event that should bring to the top, you should use an anchor tag `<a href="top" />` to bring the user to the top.

Answer (score 2):

Answer:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
var node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.Headerbg);            
if (node){
  if (window.scrollY > 50) {                  
      this.setState({...});          
  } else {                 
      this.setState({...});          
  }
}
```